# How do I create a two-page InDesign document to be printed as a double-sided sheet?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I'm trying to create a file where it shows two pages, that will eventually be printed as a double-sided sheet.

I'm using InDesign CC, OS X, 10.9.4.

I have already created the first page. And I'm trying to figure out how to copy the first page exactly to make the second page—making a document in English, and then German on the other side. They should be exactly the same, other than the text.

What do I need to do to copy the first page to make the second?
What particular settings do I need to have so this should be no problem for the printer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make Sure you plan according to the way the printer workks, if it flips on the short side of the paper or on the long side of the paper (actual printer language). Most printers you can choose which side to flip.
   [image]
2. To make life easier - **always align everything to the center!** if you have a square align it to center, if you have two, group them with the same space between them and align them to center and so on...
   [image]
3. Everything you print, print with crop marks! it's the best way to check if the printer is flipping correctly - sometimes we don't know if we did something wrong or the printer is not flipping correctly because of malfunction or an error at the printers, so add to the printer settings (or ask the person printing) to add crop marks. If the crop marks double sides fit but the rest doesn't you made a mistake, if the flip doesn't fit the crop marks, the problem was in the printing and not in the file.

Comment: The images imply you are recommending spreads, but I gather from the text that you are just offering side-by-side thumbnails. I think point number one is information pertaining to duplex on a printer-as-in-HP-laserjet, not web offset.

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate a page in InDesign, click and drag the Page thumbnail in the **Pages Panel** to the `New Page` icon at the bottom of the panel.

[image]

This will *duplicate* the page exactly creating a new page.